# Need to join 2 columns into only one using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to join 2 columns into only one as follows.

[image]

Comment: Try using `UNION`?

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use union

If both the columns are in the same table

```
select connection from my_table
union 
select followed_id from my_table
```

or change the table name if are in different tables

```
select connection from my_table1
union 
select followed_id from my_table2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (
    select follower_id from T
    union
    select followed_id from T
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are in one table then use `cross join` with `lateral`. It uses just one table scan.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   table, LATERAL (
   VALUES
      (follower_id )
    , (followed_id)  -- data types must be compatible
   ) v ("connections")
```

similar question: [Select distinct on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/102702#102702)

Comment: How is this different than `UNION` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I believe it uses just one table scan

Answer (score 0):

Union works, I would also add "order by"

```
select a.follower_id "Connections" 
from table_name a 
union 
select b.followed_id
from table_name b
order by "Connections"
```